# $L^p$-norm of the remainder of $L^2$-bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We have a sequence of functions $(u_n)$ bounded in $L^2(M)$, where $M$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We represent the sequence $(u_n)$ in the orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}_{k\in N}$ of $L^2(M)$:
$$
u_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a^n_k e_k(x)
$$ Is it true
$$
\lim\limits_{s\to \infty} \sup\limits_{n\in N} \|\sum\limits_{k=s}^\infty a^n_k e_k(\cdot)\|_{L^p(M)}=0, \ \ 1\leq p<2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $p \in [1,2]$ $$\|f 1_{|f| > 1}\|_p^p \le \|f \|_2^2, \qquad \qquad \|f 1_{|f| \le 1}\|_p^p \le \|f \|_1 $$
With Cauchy-Schwarz $$\|f \|_1\le \|f\|_2\|1_M\|_2$$
Thus $$\|f\|_p^p=\|f 1_{|f| > 1}\|_p^p+\|f 1_{|f| \le 1}\|_p^p \le \|f\|_2^2+ \|1_M \|_2 \|f\|_2$$

Let $U_{n,s} = \sum_{k=s}^\infty a^n_k e_k$. You have said $\sup_n \|U_{n,1}\|_2 < \infty$ but this is not enough, try with $a^n_k= 1_{n=k}$, you probably meant 
$\lim_{s \to \infty} \sup_n \|U_{n,s}\|_2=  0$ which implies $\lim_{s \to \infty} \sup_n \|U_{n,s}\|_p=  0$.